# Entering in an accompanied visa but then separating

Tags: uk

Is it ok If we enter the country together however the adult leaves them in the state to go travel?

Comment: They will check the same condition on exit as well. If you don't abide by it expect  some troubles.

Comment: You might possibly raise concerns about [child-trafficking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trafficking_of_children).